# Why does forward slash after login.php break image display?

Tags: php, html, apache

A little background. My company's xss scanner found that login.php was vulnerable to:

```
https://uzypav/login.php/ab7e7%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3da%20onerror%3dalert(1)%3E47eee
```

This has been addressed with htmlentities().

I noticed however that a forward slash ("/") after my script name (`https://uzypav/login.php/`) stops images from displaying and yet it displays my content.

1. Is this normal?
2. Is there a way to guard against this?
3. Is this a 404 situation?

See my code below. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<div style="background-image:url(images/back.jpg)">
<h1>LOGIN</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" /><br>
    <input id="password" type="text" name="password" value="" /><br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<?php
if(@$_POST["submit"] == "submit")
    echo "submitted";


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest opening some web debugger and viewing the http requests. You will probably see requests to missing resource.

Since the image path does not start with "/", it's a relative path. Relative to the current directory, which is the root directory in the case of `https://uzypav/login.php`.

When you add a forward slash, the current directory is `https://uzypav/login.php/` and the browser makes a request for `https://uzypav/login.php/images/back.jpg` - which does not exist (probably)

Comment: I need to disallow all requests with trailing "/" (slash).  

I read that one can redirect `https://uzypav/*.php/` to `https://uzypav/error404.php` using Apache mod_rewrite. All the examples I found did not address my specific case.  

Note that I also have scripts in sub-folders like `https://uzypav/scheduled_jobs/bulk/*.php`  

FYI: I do not expect nor do I process any $_GET values. Its all $_POST values.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I searched and replaced all relative image and <a href paths to full paths. Works like a charm. 
src="images/ to src="<?php echo $ROOTURL;?>/images/

src='images/ to src='<?php echo $ROOTURL;?>/images/, etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes this is normal see answer from @RoyBass
2. Yes you can set the full image path `https://uzypav/images/back.jpg` in the url thing from css
3. You could probably, because the user access something what he shouldn't, but you can do `2.` and just ignore that.

Comment: Wow. RoyBass and Jannis are both right. But how practicable is it to change image full path from development machine to production? Is this a case of using a global full root url variable?

Comment: @uzy , well, you could do also use ``/images/back.jpg``, then you do not need to add the domain

Comment: FYI: I am unable to mark answers as correct. I am told I don't have enough points.@Jannis, I doubt that /images/back.jpg addresses my challenge, but full url does. But how do I apply it to existing site taking into account; javascripts, jquery, dhtml_goodies, etc?

Comment: @uzy There is a correct mark und that voting with the arrows, that you need to click, 2. you may need to adjust all links/path to all resources you use, else they will probably not get included